# Is PHP's header function a CPU-heavy task to do for redirecting to video files?

Tags: php

As we have CPU restrictions on the server. And what about PHP's readfile function?

Comment: Do you mean the http://php.net/header function?

Comment: yes, that same function I meant

Answer (score 1):

No; calling `header` simply outputs an HTTP header to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it has nothing to do with the CPU, there might be something with your internet speed, the server response time and its speed.